# White little larvae/insects on the trunk of my Pilea

Tags: houseplants, pests

I have a healthy (or so I thought) Pilea plant (Chinese Money), ~6 months old, indoors. Today, I noticed some strange little white dots on its trunk; and, as it turns out, they are moving, and seem to be some sort of larvae. (I'm attaching two pictures of those.)

What are those? Are they dangerous? What should I do?

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems like a type of scale, perhaps wax scale. Scale live off plant sap and leave a sticky substance on the plant.  I would put the plant in a plastic bag, spray in your favorite pesticide and close up the bag and leave it for a few days(all outside).  Check the plant.  Repeat if necessary.  You may want to replace the soil. Do not put the soil in your garden.  Scale can be tricky to kill.

Comment: Thank you -- I'll look into that asap!